# What piece of music is this from?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

This has been rattling around my head for a while. Please help identify.
My closest approximation of the sheet music:
[image]

Comment: Hi Zach. Thanks for the post. Please including as much description as you can, in case the link eventually becomes inactive. Also, please embed the score as a picture.

Comment: Could it be Gabriel Fauré's "[Pavane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhiVuIRw4tM)"?

Comment: I figured it out! It's Greig! Last Spring. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Congratulations. You can post that as an answer to your own question. That way others will know you found you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **The Last Spring** from [Two Elegiac Melodies, Op.34](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Elegiac_Melodies) by [Edvard Grieg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edvard_Grieg) completed in 1880 and first published in 1881.

*The music is in G major. There are two verses: in both the melody is played by the first violins...*